# Customising headings/counters using scrartcl class

Tags: sectioning, koma-script, counters

I would like to recreate the following behaviour using the `scrartcl` class:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{}{Aufgabe \thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]{}{\alph{subsection})}{1em}{}
\begin{document}
\section{}
\subsection{}
\end{document}
```

Which then looks like this:

[image]

I did not for the life of it find a way to achieve the same using a KOMA-class (`scrartcl`, to be precise), so I resorted to doing this:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\begin{document}
\section*{Aufgabe 1}
\subsection*{a)}
\end{document}
```

Which is feasible because we're only talking 3–5 pages long assignments and I don't need a TOC, but it's of course horribly un-LaTeX-ish and part of me is dying when I do it.

Comment: If you have something like "Ausgabe" and maybe "Lösung", I would suggest to use [`exsheets`](https://ctan.org/pkg/exsheets) or [a similar package](http://ctan.org/topic/exercise).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: koma]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\alph{subsection}}
\renewcommand*\sectionformat{Aufgabe \thesection}
\renewcommand*\subsectionformat{\thesubsection)\hspace*{1em}}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[afterskip=0pt]{subsection}
\setkomafont{section}{\rmfamily\mdseries}
\setkomafont{subsection}{\rmfamily\mdseries}
\begin{document}
\section{}
\subsection{}
Blub
\end{document}
```

---

*Update:* An alternative approach would be enumerations:

[image: enumerations]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{needspace}

\newcounter{aufgabecnt}
\newenvironment{aufgabe}{
    \needspace{3\baselineskip}\bfseries Aufgabe \stepcounter{aufgabecnt}\theaufgabecnt:\mdseries\nopagebreak
    \begin{enumerate}[label={\alph*)}]
}{\end{enumerate}}

\begin{document}
\begin{aufgabe}
    \item Test
    \item Test
\end{aufgabe}
\end{document}
```

This approach uses the package `needspace` for preventing page breaks (as `\nopagebreak` is kind of tricky).

Comment: I do highlight them in the actual document. I removed all formatting from the mwe because it's not part of the issue. Point taken for the break though. I took care of that in the document but accidentally removed it from the mwe. I'll add it.

Comment: »Issuing empty sections and subsections does not make much sense.« – why not?

Comment: @clemens Well, because a simple new command with so much hassle of redefinitions would have been sufficient. But I have already removed those points as they were not that important.

Comment: @TeXnician I don't get it but I guess it's not so important…